# auto set options in own package

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

it is probably `bad style` but can I modify options on package loading? E.g. my package should set the following options

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")
options(dplyr.width = Inf)
lattice.options(default.args = list(as.table = TRUE))
lattice.options(skip.boundary.labels = 0)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, of course you *can* -- use the `.onAttach()` function for that. You then may want to make sure you document this, though, and maybe restore it when the package unloads.

Whether you *should* is not so clear. As an alternative (which may be more common) you can also set *personal preferences* in `~/.Rprofile` or the site-wide `Rprofile.site`. I often do that for myself and colleagues for things like remote server settings.

Comment: Example use of `.onAttach()` to set package options in the 
[rpushbullet package by Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rpushbullet/blob/master/R/init.R).